# Can't copy AWS RDS DB snapshot because of key not existing or no access? (Administrator account)

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services

I have administrator access to my AWS account and I'm trying to copy a DB snapshot that has has encryption on it. I'm specifying the key ID but it's still giving me the following error:

> /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.124.0/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:17:in
> `call': The target KMS key [<my_key_id>] does not exist, is not
> enabled or you do not have permissions to access it.
> (Aws::RDS::Errors::KMSKeyNotAccessibleFault)

The only thing that has changed from the time it worked to the time it no longer works is me enabling encryption on the database, so now its snapshots are encrypted. As a result, I've added the `kms_key_id` parameter to my `copy_db_snapshot` method.

Here's how I'm doing this with the `aws-sdk-rds` gem:

```
  client.copy_db_snapshot({
                            source_db_snapshot_identifier: source_db_arn,
                            target_db_snapshot_identifier: target_db_snapshot_identifier,
                            source_region: source_db_region,
                            kms_key_id: '<my_key_id>'
                          })
```

I don't quite fully understand this error message. The key definitely exists (I've tried just the key ID and the full ARN), and I definitely have permission. I'm using a key generated by AWS so not sure if this helps.

Comment: What is the key policy for your KMS key?

Comment: @KaustubhKhavnekar the default policy by AWS since it's an AWS managed key. Am I SOL because of that?

Comment: Are you cpying it to another account region?  Can you describe the key from that account/region(using cli)?

Comment: I'm copying it from one region to another region in the same account @riz. From there, my goal is to restore the snapshot into an RDS instance into that other region. That works fine as long as encryption isn't enabled, but having encryption enabled seems to break the process, even just the snapshot copy.

Comment: Ok, so it seems like you can't copy snapshot encrypted by aws default kms. What you can do is explained here. https://aws.amazon.com/it/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/share-encrypted-rds-snapshot-kms-key/

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/RDS/Client.html#copy_db_snapshot-instance_method

> If you copy an encrypted snapshot to a different Amazon Web Services
> Region, then you must specify an Amazon Web Services KMS key
> identifier for the destination Amazon Web Services Region. KMS keys
> are specific to the Amazon Web Services Region that they are created
> in, and you can't use KMS keys from one Amazon Web Services Region in
> another Amazon Web Services Region.

You need to specify the KMS key id of a KMS key in the **destination region**. This is because the `kms_key_id` parameter is actually supposed to be the ID of the KMS Key used to encrypt the new snapshot copy, not your original snapshot.